# hom functor exactness and group cohomology

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology

On one hand we have this lemma: let $A_1\rightarrow A_2 \rightarrow A_3\rightarrow 0$ be exact sequence of G-modules. Then $0\rightarrow \text{Hom} _G(A_3,M)\rightarrow \text{Hom} _G(A_2,M) \rightarrow \text{Hom} _G(A_1,M)$ is exact sequence of Abelian groups.

But on the other hand we have definition of group cohomology: let $\bf{P}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be projective resolution of $G$-module $\mathbb{Z}$. Form new sequence:
$$
\ldots \rightarrow \text{Hom} _G(P_{n-1},M)\rightarrow \text{Hom} _G(P_n,M)\rightarrow \text{Hom} _G(P_{n+1},M)\rightarrow \ldots
$$

Cohomology groups are $H^n(G,M)=\text{ker } \delta _{n+1}/\text{im } \delta _n$ (where $\delta _{n+1}: \text{Hom} _G(P_{n},M)\rightarrow \text{Hom} _G(P_{n+1},M)$).

But according to the lemma above this sequence should be exact ($\text{ker }\delta _{n+1}=\text{im }\delta _n$, cohomology groups should vanish). What am I missing?

edit: fixed the lemma.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are saying this sequence should be exact.  Maybe you are confused about what it means to be left exact.

Comment: The projective resolution is exact by definition, so why isn't Hom sequence also exact by that lemma?

Comment: In your lemma, you assumed that you had a short exact sequence. Which short exact sequence are you applying the lemma to?

Comment: $\ldots \rightarrow P_1 \rightarrow P_0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$ is projective resolution. We can take $P_1 \rightarrow P_0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: pardon, double post

Comment: You didn't answer the question. What exactly are $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$ in your application of the lemma that proves that $H^n(G,M)=0$?

Comment: $A_1=P_1$, $A_2=P_0$, $A_3=\mathbb{Z}$. Ok, maybe not all cohomology groups are equal to zero, but $H^0(G,M)$ and $H^1(G,A)$ are (at least according to this lemma).

Comment: But $0 \to P_1 \to P_0$ is not exact so the lemma does not apply.

Comment: Sorry, I have not stated lemma properly. It is not necessary to assume that $0\rightarrow P_1\rightarrow P_2$ is exact. I will edit the lemma in the original post.

Comment: Your argument does not apply to $H^1(G,M)$. In fact $H^0(G,M)$ is just defined to be $\ker \delta_0$ which is equal to $M^G$. (Your indexing is out by $1$ from the normal conventions, which has $P_1 \to P_0 \to {\mathbb Z} \to 0$.)

Comment: I can see now, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that instead of applying $\operatorname{Hom}_G(-,M)$ to $P_\bullet \to \mathbf{Z} \to 0$, you should be applying $\operatorname{Hom}_G(-,M)$ to $P_\bullet \to 0$. That is, you would be right that since
$$\cdots \to P_1 \to P_0 \to \mathbf{Z} \to 0$$
is exact, applying $\operatorname{Hom}_G(-,M)$ would give
$$0 \to \operatorname{Hom}_G(\mathbf{Z},M) \to \operatorname{Hom}_G(P_0,M) \to \operatorname{Hom}_G(P_1,M) \to \cdots$$
which is also exact up to $\operatorname{Hom}_G(P_0,M)$. On the other hand, in the definition of derived functors you apply your functor to the *resolution* $P_\bullet$, without the augmentation to $\mathbf{Z}$, i.e., we take the sequence
$$\cdots \to P_2 \to P_1 \to P_0 \to 0$$
which is not exact at $P_0$ anymore, and apply $\operatorname{Hom}_G(-,M)$ to give
$$0 \to \operatorname{Hom}_G(P_0,M) \to \operatorname{Hom}_G(P_1,M) \to \operatorname{Hom}_G(P_2,M) \to \cdots$$
which we have no information about from your Lemma. Group cohomology is the cohomology of *this* complex.